primarySwatch not working in flutter in android
I am currently learning flutter and used "primarySwatch" in my to-do app. But it is not working. I don't know what to do. I have used the color yellow but its showing white.

I tried many things ->

Looking for solutions
Flutter sdk reinstallation
Formatted the laptop but noting happened.


Refer background color property of amber to change it to the required color

You should now use colorScheme instead of primarySwatch, as the latter is there for historical reasons and may not completely covers all aspects of the theme.

Use colorSchemeSeed instead.

[colorScheme] is the preferred way to configure colors. The other color properties (as well as primarySwatch) will gradually be phased out, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/91772.

MaterialApp(
  theme: ThemeData(colorSchemeSeed: Colors.yellow),
...
);


I have used StatefulWidget instead of StatelessWidget
My code:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blue,
        useMaterial3: true
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});
  
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: const Text("Registration"),
      ),
    );
  }
}

I actually donot understand why it works but still.. I works just as I expected

Solution:
The issue is that primarySwatch expects a MaterialColor, but Colors.yellow is just a Color. To fix this, you need to create a custom MaterialColor. Here’s how you can do it:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: createMaterialColor(Color(0xFFFFEB3B)), // Custom yellow color
      ),
    );
  }
}

MaterialColor createMaterialColor(Color color) {
  List strengths = <double>[.05];
  final swatch = <int, Color>{};
  final int r = color.red, g = color.green, b = color.blue;

  for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    strengths.add(0.1 * i);
  }
  for (var strength in strengths) {
    final double ds = 0.5 - strength;
    swatch[(strength * 1000).round()] = Color.fromRGBO(
      r + ((ds < 0 ? r : (255 - r)) * ds).round(),
      g + ((ds < 0 ? g : (255 - g)) * ds).round(),
      b + ((ds < 0 ? b : (255 - b)) * ds).round(),
      1,
    );
  }
  return MaterialColor(color.value, swatch);
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('To-Do List'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Hello World'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Alternatively, if you don’t need a custom color and can use a predefined material swatch, you can do this:
theme: ThemeData(
  primarySwatch: Colors.amber, // Predefined swatch
),

This should resolve the issue and apply the correct color to your app.
Tags: [flutter] [dart] [flutter-layout] [flutter-theme]

The pre-defined swatch is also not working I tried it. Is there any easy way to make custom colors as I am a beginner in Flutter?

Use the primaryColor instead of primarySwatch
The primaryColor can be used directly to set the primary color of your app

primaryColor: Colors.yellow,

There is no color in my app bar it is still white.

Does primarySwatch only works in ios? or it also works in android?

The primarySwatch works on both iOS and Android. However, it requires a MaterialColor, not just a simple Color like Colors.yellow. Make sure to use a predefined MaterialColor or create a custom one if needed.

okay let me try. Thanks for the help :)
